# Считывание текстового файла при пересоздании StreamReader в каждой итерации

Tags: c#, io

Есть код:

```
static void Main()
{
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\ab\1.txt", FileMode.Open);
    for (int x = 0; x < fs.Length; x++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(new StreamReader(fs).Read());
    }
}
```

Я по недосмотру поставил `new StreamReader(fs).Read()`, и получилось, что вначале выводится код первого символа, а потом все `-1`.

Почему выводится `-1`, а не всё время повторяющийся код первого символа?

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, текущая позиция для считывания из файла хранится в самом `FileStream`. А `StreamReader` лишь предоставляет удобства при считывании данных, опираясь при этом на работу самого `FileStream`.

Comment: Да, это так. Если, допустим, текущая позиция FileStream лежит в 1, то все равно по идее, должен все время выводиться код символа по индексу [1], а он выводит -1, что обозначает конец строки

Comment: @polyakov_s, каждый read двигает указатель дальше. Так что одно значение он может выводить лишь в двух случаях: когда файл состоит из повторяющихся значений или когда уже ничего в файле нет. В других случаях Read будет возвращать разные значения, которые соответствуют сдвинутому указателю

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Повторяющийся символ не выводится, потому что метод `StreamReader.Read()` сдвигает позицию нижележащего стрима -- `FileStream`. Он у вас один, а `StreamReader` каждый раз новый. Чтоб выводился первый символ, надо на каждой итерации цикла возвращать позицию исходного стрима в начало:

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\ab\1.txt", FileMode.Open);
for (int x = 0; x < fs.Length; x++)
{
    fs.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    Console.WriteLine(new StreamReader(fs).Read());
}
```

Почему выводится первый символ на итерации x=0, думаю, понятно.

Теперь о том, почему дальше идут -1. `StreamReader` имеет внутренний буфер -- по умолчанию 1024 байта. Соответственно при первом вызове `StreamReader.Read()` буфер заполняется и позиция нижележащего стрима сдвигается. В случае, если размер нижележащего стрима меньше, чем 1024 байта, то при первом вызове `StreamReader.Read()` все содержимое будет прочитано и позиция будет указывать на конец. Соответственно следующие итерации возвращают -1, потому что достигнут конец стрима. Очевидно, это ваш случай. Убедиться в этом можно, например, так:

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\ab\1.txt", FileMode.Open);
Console.WriteLine("Length " + fs.Length);
for (int x = 0; x < fs.Length; x++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(new StreamReader(fs).Read() + " - new pos " + fs.Position);
}
```

Можно было бы избавиться от такого поведения, указав размер буфера в 1:

```
new StreamReader(fs, Encoding.UTF8, true, 1)
```

Но `StreamReader` имеет встроенный минимальный размер буфера в 128, поэтому поможет это несильно :).

P.S. Не забывайте оборачивать стримы в `using`!

Comment: Ох, великолепно. Спасибо. Не догадался бы

Comment: @polyakov_s не за что. В случае сомнений -- http://sourceof.net :).

Answer (score 3):

[Документация](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ath1fht8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) говорит:

> Возвращаемое значение
>   Следующий символ из входного потока, представленного в виде объекта `Int32`, или значение -1, если больше нет доступных символов.

`StreamReader` потому и потоковый, что читает не один байт, а много, буферизирует их, разбивает на строки и отдаёт по запросу. Таким образом, первый цикл, судя по всему, вычитал *весь* файл из `FileStream` в `StreamReader` (теперь текущая позиция в `fs` — конец файла), и следующий цикл начинает чтение с текущей позиции в `fs`, то есть с конца. Признаком того, что `StreamReader` видит конец потока, и есть `-1`.

Comment: Но там ведь есть след. символы, он просто натыкается все время на один и тот же символ и выводит почему-то -1 вместо его значения

Comment: @polyakov_s: Обновил ответ.